# C# Асинхронные сокеты

Tags: c#, сокеты

Изучаю пример от MSDN:

Server

```
class Server  {
    private int m_numConnections;
    private int m_receiveBufferSize;
    BufferManager m_bufferManager;
    const int opsToPreAlloc = 2; 
    Socket listenSocket;
    SocketAsyncEventArgsPool m_readWritePool;
    int m_totalBytesRead; 
    int m_numConnectedSockets;
    Semaphore m_maxNumberAcceptedClients;

    public Server(int numConnections, int receiveBufferSize) {
      m_totalBytesRead = 0;
      m_numConnectedSockets = 0;
      m_numConnections = numConnections;
      m_receiveBufferSize = receiveBufferSize;
      m_bufferManager = new BufferManager(receiveBufferSize * numConnections * opsToPreAlloc,
          receiveBufferSize);
      m_readWritePool = new SocketAsyncEventArgsPool(numConnections);
      m_maxNumberAcceptedClients = new Semaphore(numConnections, numConnections);
    }

    public void Init()  {
      m_bufferManager.InitBuffer();
      SocketAsyncEventArgs readWriteEventArg;
      for (int i = 0; i < m_numConnections; i++) {
        readWriteEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        readWriteEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(IO_Completed);
        readWriteEventArg.UserToken = new AsyncUserToken();
        m_bufferManager.SetBuffer(readWriteEventArg);
        m_readWritePool.Push(readWriteEventArg);
      }
    }

    public void Start(IPEndPoint localEndPoint) {
      listenSocket = new Socket(localEndPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
      listenSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);
      listenSocket.Listen(100);
      StartAccept(null);
    }

    public void StartAccept(SocketAsyncEventArgs acceptEventArg) {
      if (acceptEventArg == null) {
        acceptEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        acceptEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(AcceptEventArg_Completed);
      }
      else {
        acceptEventArg.AcceptSocket = null;
      }
      m_maxNumberAcceptedClients.WaitOne();
      bool willRaiseEvent = listenSocket.AcceptAsync(acceptEventArg);
      if (!willRaiseEvent) {
        ProcessAccept(acceptEventArg);
      }
    }

    void AcceptEventArg_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e) {
      ProcessAccept(e);        
    }

    private void ProcessAccept(SocketAsyncEventArgs e) {
      Interlocked.Increment(ref m_numConnectedSockets);
      SocketAsyncEventArgs readEventArgs = m_readWritePool.Pop();
      ((AsyncUserToken)readEventArgs.UserToken).Socket = e.AcceptSocket;
      bool willRaiseEvent = e.AcceptSocket.ReceiveAsync(readEventArgs);
      if (!willRaiseEvent) {
        ProcessReceive(readEventArgs);
      }
      StartAccept(e);
    }

    void IO_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e) {
      switch (e.LastOperation) {
        case SocketAsyncOperation.Receive:
          ProcessReceive(e);
          break;
        case SocketAsyncOperation.Send:
          ProcessSend(e);
          break;
        default:
          throw new ArgumentException("The last operation completed on the socket was not a receive or send");
      }
    }

    private void ProcessReceive(SocketAsyncEventArgs e) {
      AsyncUserToken token = (AsyncUserToken)e.UserToken;
      if (e.BytesTransferred > 0 && e.SocketError == SocketError.Success) {
        Interlocked.Add(ref m_totalBytesRead, e.BytesTransferred);
        e.SetBuffer(e.Offset, e.BytesTransferred);
        bool willRaiseEvent = token.Socket.SendAsync(e);
        if (!willRaiseEvent) {
          ProcessSend(e);
        }
      }
      else {
        CloseClientSocket(e);
      }
    }

    private void ProcessSend(SocketAsyncEventArgs e) {
      if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success) {
        AsyncUserToken token = (AsyncUserToken)e.UserToken;
        bool willRaiseEvent = token.Socket.ReceiveAsync(e);
        if (!willRaiseEvent) {
          ProcessReceive(e);
        }
      }
      else {
        CloseClientSocket(e);
      }
    }

    private void CloseClientSocket(SocketAsyncEventArgs e) {
      AsyncUserToken token = e.UserToken as AsyncUserToken;
      try {
        token.Socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);
      }
      catch (Exception) { }
      token.Socket.Close();
      Interlocked.Decrement(ref m_numConnectedSockets);
      m_maxNumberAcceptedClients.Release();
      m_readWritePool.Push(e);
    }
  }
```

SocketAsyncEventArgsPool

```
class SocketAsyncEventArgsPool {
    Stack<SocketAsyncEventArgs> m_pool;

    public SocketAsyncEventArgsPool(int capacity) {
        m_pool = new Stack<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(capacity);
    }

    public void Push(SocketAsyncEventArgs item) {
      if (item == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("Items added to a SocketAsyncEventArgsPool cannot be null"); }
      lock (m_pool) {
        m_pool.Push(item);
      }
    }

    public SocketAsyncEventArgs Pop() {
      lock (m_pool) {
        return m_pool.Pop();
      }
    }

    public int Count {
      get { return m_pool.Count; }
    }
  }
```

BufferManager

```
class BufferManager {
    int m_numBytes;          
    byte[] m_buffer;               
    Stack<int> m_freeIndexPool;    
    int m_currentIndex;
    int m_bufferSize;

    public BufferManager(int totalBytes, int bufferSize) {
      m_numBytes = totalBytes;
      m_currentIndex = 0;
      m_bufferSize = bufferSize;
      m_freeIndexPool = new Stack<int>();
    }

    public void InitBuffer() {
      m_buffer = new byte[m_numBytes];
    }

    public bool SetBuffer(SocketAsyncEventArgs args) {
      if (m_freeIndexPool.Count > 0) {
        args.SetBuffer(m_buffer, m_freeIndexPool.Pop(), m_bufferSize);
      }
      else {
        if ((m_numBytes - m_bufferSize) < m_currentIndex) {
          return false;
        }
        args.SetBuffer(m_buffer, m_currentIndex, m_bufferSize);
        m_currentIndex += m_bufferSize;
      }
      return true;
    }

    public void FreeBuffer(SocketAsyncEventArgs args) {
      m_freeIndexPool.Push(args.Offset);
      args.SetBuffer(null, 0, 0);
    }
  }

 internal class AsyncUserToken {
    public System.Net.Sockets.Socket Socket { get; set; }
 }
```

Смортю здесь используют Stack, у меня вопрос, как работать с каждым сокетом отдельно? Как идентифицировать соединение и например отсоединить? Буду рад помощи

Цикл

```html
public void sendToAll() {
  foreach(SocketAsyncEventArgs eventargs in m_pool) {
    AsyncUserToken token = eventargs.UserToken as AsyncUserToken;
    token.Socket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Test"));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не работал с сокетами в C#, но там как и везде обязан быть некий идентификатор соединения, доступный из сохраняемого списка и при каждой обработке сообщения.

В приведённом коде на такой идентификатор смахивает поле `UserToken` объекта `SocketAsyncEventArgs`. Это значение можно легко получать (оно есть в аргументах всех методов работы с клиентами), и с его же помощью можно манипулировать соединением, отправлять сообщения.

MSDN говорит, что [класс `Socket`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx) имеет [метод `Close()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.socket.close(v=vs.110).aspx) для отключения соединения. Объект `UserToken` как раз имеет соответствующее поле `Socket`. И оно используется в методе `CloseClientSocket`, который, в свою очередь, и производит нужное Вам действие — отключает клиента, при этом, вежливо его уведомляя и удаляя соединение из списка `SocketAsyncEventArgsPool`.

Comment: Но как к примеру получить всех клиентов и всем отправить сообщение?

Comment: Я сделал foreach цикл по m_pool но реакции нету

Comment: Объект `SocketAsyncEventArgsPool` хранит все подключения в `m_pool`, проходясь по нему циклом можно выполнять требуемые действия.

Comment: @MikeWaters а что было в Вашем цикле?

Comment: добавил в вопросе, token.Socket ловит System.NullReferenceException

Comment: @MikeWaters нашёл причину: в методе `Init()` создаётся множество объектов `SocketAsyncEventArgs` в `m_pool`, при этом, в `UserToken` добавляется новый объект, но без добавления какого-либо значения. И поэтому `token` не имеет `Socket`.

Comment: Вообще, это какая-то странная механика, использовать стек вместо нормального списка, да ещё и с заранее заложенными значениями. Возможно, этот код создан для повышенной производительности, однако как пример он весьма неполный, советую поискать что-нибудь внятнее или же написать полностью самому, если достаточно энтузиазма.

Comment: Да наверное пойду на список делать...